# Some Quote Numbers are not showing in my custom Report

Tags: salesforcedx, configuration, quote, custom-reports

I have a group of rows of Service Branch and Quote Number, Service Branch is "MO Branch", and Other Quote numbers have the value of Service Branch "MO Branch". My question is why other Quote Numbers are not showing in the group rows? Ex: Q-132501 has the value of Service Branch "MO Branch" but it did not appear on the report [image]

Comment: Check sharing access to these records.

Comment: Do you have any other filters on your report? And are you sure it's the same MO Branch record? There could be multiple accounts with the same name.

Comment: @GuyClairbois I don't have any filters on my report. Yes I'm sure that the other quote number have same MO Branch record

Comment: @PhilW  done check sharing access to these records. it's all for internal users. and as an admin, it should show all data on my end